# How to change the color of a td based on bookings?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to make color red when the room is booked? I don't know what should I put for the if statement when I want the color to change. I have currently just sql2 but I don't know how I should do it. All help is appreciated.

```
function fDisplayARoomSection($date){
global $servername, $password, $dbname, $username;

//connect to the database----------
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
  die ("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//Prepare the SQL statement and send it to the database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rooms ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

//Loop through the resulting set of records

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<div style=\"background-color:AliceBlue;\">";
    echo "<hr style=\"\">";
    echo "<p style=\"margin-bottom:.1em;margin-top:.1em;\"><a href=\"\">Room: " .$row["RoomNumber"] ."</a></p>"; 
    echo "<table style=\"border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;\">";

    //-- display hours
    echo "<tr>\n";
        for ($c=1;$c<=10;$c++){
    echo "<td colspan=\"4\" class=\"Hours\">" .(7+$c) ."</td>\n";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE bookingRoomID=" .$row["RoomID"] ." bookingDate='" .$date ."'";
    //--display timeline
    echo "<tr>";
            if ($sql2){ 
                $color="red";
            }else{
                $color="white";
            }
        echo "<td class=\"Timeline\" style=\"background-color:$color; ";
            if ($c==1){echo "border-left:1px solid black;";}    
                if ($c%4==0){echo "border-right:1px solid black;";}
                    echo "\"></td>\n";
        }

    echo "</tr></table>";
    echo "<hr style=\"\">";
    echo "</div>";


}
```

Comment: check the book room in while loop.

Comment: how would i do that? I am new to programming

Comment: In which table you will store booked room data

Comment: I have it stored in Booking as bookingfrom and booking till

Comment: I can't understand. can you share database table structure. otherwise i can't help.

Comment: Don't know how to add it but its 
BookingID, BookingRoomID, BookingUserID, BookingFrom, BookingTill, BookingDate

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the value for `Column` from your result set using `mysql_fetch_field` from sql2. You can check the value and add condition to it for conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

change like this:

```
echo '<td class="Timeline" style="background-color:'.$color.';';
```